# How do I flip the orientation of a grid?

Tags: rotation, wolfram-mathematica

I'm just doing a simple `Grid[datasymbolgoeshere, Frame->All]` command. It's taking a list of ID numbers (e.g., {11282,11281,11280}) and placing each one in its own column. I just want to flip the orientation so all strings in a single list are placed in the same column (individual rows, one on top of another), and the next list of strings goes in the second column.

Comment: if you give an example of what is in datasymbolgoeshere it'll be easier to provide an answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you want

`Grid[Transpose[datasymbolgoeshere],Frame->All]`

Edit -- by the way `Grid` assumes a multidimensional list.  It won't complain if you call, eg `Grid[{1,2}]` but Mma cannot simplify that expression and just returns it as-is.  `Grid` will work with a ragged array, but `Transpose` will complain, so you will need to pad the elements of `datasymbolgoeshere` to make your array rectangular.

Putting it all together, something like this should work on most inputs

`With[
{
    maxLength=Length/@data//Max
},
    PadRight[#,maxLength,""]&/@data//Grid[#,Frame->All]&
]`

Comment: It might also be useful to bear in mind that  [Flatten](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Flatten.html) can do a Transpose of a ragged array.  (see the example under 'Applications' in  `Flatten` Help). For example `Grid[Flatten[{{11282, 11281, 11280}, {12282, 12281, 12280}, {13282, 13281}}, {{2}, {1}}]]`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370848/pair-lists-to-create-tuples-in-order/5372194#5372194) for a discussion.  I never fully understood this one.  (Transpose will not work in the example given).

Answer (score 3):

`Rotate[Grid[datasymbolgoeshere, Frame->All],90 Degree]`

I like that the contents are still selectable.

Comment: ...and if you like the characters to stand upright you can rotate them back too: `Rotate[Grid[Map[Rotate[#, -90 Degree] &, dalist, {-1}], Frame -> All],  90 Degree]`

Comment: @Sjoerd I'd use `{2}` instead of `{-1}` for the level spec, otherwise things get interesting when your data isn't atomic, such as `Array[Sin[# #2] &, {5, 5}]`.