# using nested arrays and lists in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Absolute beginner question here.
I have two lists in mathematica. 
The first one was generated by the Table command:

`Table[QP[[i]], {i, 10}]`
which generates the list:

`{52.5, 45., 37.5, 30., 22.5, 15., 7.5, 0., -7.5, -15.}`

the second is a Range

`Range[0, 9, 1]`

which generates {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

I need to get these into a list of lists. i.e. {{0,52.5},{1,45} ... } etc. But I can't seem to get it. Do you need to use loops? Because I think that what I want can be generated with the Table and Array commands.

Thanks

Comment: Please remember to use lowercase letters as the first char in user defined symbols. You will save yourself a lot of headaches

Comment: The answers to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5370848/499167) question *Pair lists to get tuples in order* may also be of interest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first parameter of `Table` can be any expression. You can have it output a list of lists, by specifying a list as the first parameter:

```
Table[{i-1, QP[[i]]}, {i, 10}]
(* {{0, QP[[1]]}, {1, QP[[2]]}, ... {8, QP[[9]]}, {9, QP[[10]]}} *)
```

Answer (score 7):

`Transpose` may be what you want:

```
list1 = {52.5, 45., 37.5, 30., 22.5, 15., 7.5, 0., -7.5, -15.}

list2 = Range[0, 9, 1]
Transpose[{list2, list1}]
```

gives

> {{0, 52.5}, {1, 45.}, {2, 37.5}, {3, 30.}, {4, 22.5}, {5, 15.}, {6, 
>     7.5}, {7, 0.}, {8, -7.5}, {9, -15.}}

Comment: Reviewing the answers and comparing with [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5370848/499167), I notice that only `Flatten` has been omitted (which also allow a Transpose of a 'ragged' array). This is easy to forget! See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370848/pair-lists-to-create-tuples-in-order/5372194#5372194).  `Flatten[{list2, list1}, {{2}}] == Transpose[{list2, list1}]`

Answer (score 5):

```
Thread[List[Range[0, 9], QP[[;; 10]]]]
```

Comment: Morale: if you don't need a temp symbol to save an intermediate result, don't use it.

Comment: and @rcollyer  Why not simply...`Thread[List[Range[0,9], QP]`?  Isn't QP a list?

Comment: @David Because from the question I guessed that Length@QP > 10. I may be wrong, of course

Comment: yeah it's because i'm a history student not a computer scientist. that's why i notice these useless things. :P

Answer (score 4):

To complete the exposition of methods, you could use [`MapIndexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapIndexed.html)

```
MapIndexed[{First[#2] - 1,#1}&, data]
```

where

```
data = {52.5, 45., 37.5, 30., 22.5, 15., 7.5, 0., -7.5, -15.}
```

Or, you could use [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapThread.html)

```
MapThread[List, {Range[0,9], data}]
```

Although, `MapIndexed` is more appropriate since it does not require you to generate an extra list.

A last point I want to make is that your code `Table[QP[[i]], {i, 10}]` implies that `QP` itself is a list. (The double brackets, `[[ ]]`,  gave it away.) If that is correct, than `Table` isn't the best way to generate a subset, you can use `Part` ([`[[ ]]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html)) along with [`Span`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Span.html) directly

```
QP[[ 1 ;; 10 ]]
```

or

```
QP[[ ;; 10 ]]
```

Then, you can replace `data` in the first bits of code with either of those forms.

Comment: You stealer! Give me back my `offset by one` in your MapIndexed! :)

Comment: @belisarius, fine! Happy now!  :)